# Android Facebook using LoginManager & setting permissions

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to use LoginManager and set permissions when a user logs in.  I'd like `publish_actions` to be available for the user.

I'm using LoginManager like so:

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    //Do stuff when the login is complete
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Login Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Login Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Now, I want to add a permissions line:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(StartPage.this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

I'm not sure where to put this though.  When I put it outside of the first `LoginManager` (either before or after) I get some infinite loop of logging into facebook and the facebook modal says "you've already allowed my app".

**How do I set permissions when I use LoginManager?**
Also, Is there a way to **not** show the "You've already allowed this app" screen when logging in?

**UPDATE** for clarity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_page);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    ...

    final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    // If using in a fragment
    //loginButton.setFragment();
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    loginButton.clearPermissions();
                    loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

                    facebook_id = user.optString("id");
                    facebook_name.setText(user.optString("name"));
                    facebook_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    exc_share_facebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    share_facebook_user.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    share_facebook_auto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.optString("id"));
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant grant read and publish permission at the same time , first grant read permission and clear permission before request publish one

```
_loginfb=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fblogin);

    _loginfb.setReadPermissions(mReadPermissions);

    _loginfb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            final Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "id, email, name, picture.type(large)");

            System.out.println("Success callback");
            GraphRequest mRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                            _loginfb.clearPermissions();
                            _loginfb.setPublishPermissions(mPublishPermissions);
                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                // handle error

                            } else {

                                String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);



                            }
                        }
                    });
            mRequest.setParameters(params);
            mRequest.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }


    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: But where?  That's the same thing as the second line of code in my OP.  Not sure where to put it

Comment: So what you have there is using facebook's login example.  I've used that as well with some errors, but I'll try this again

Comment: Ok, So I changed everything to using the button, but now I'm getting an error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.registerCallback(com.facebook.CallbackManager, com.facebook.FacebookCallback)' on a null object reference`  I've initiated button in the mainactivity and oncreate, but nothing seems to be doing the trick.  Any ideas for this?

Comment: the trick if you request two types of permission (read , publish) , you need clear old one(read) before request new one(publish )

Comment: I gotcha.  This only works with LoginButton?  Or could it work with LoginManager too?

Comment: this how it works with me , I search a lot and ask every one , but no one answer me , so for easy solution use this code

Comment: Thanks Mina. Did you use a fragment for the login button? If so, could you share that example with me? I keep getting 'null' on the button even though it's there...

Comment: I cant get this please provide your whole class with some comment to describe your current state

Comment: I've just updated my code to reflect more of what you have there.  I just keep getting null object on the button, like the button doesn't exist.  I made sure it's in the view, but it's not registering or something...

Comment: Alright, I had to wrap the entire thing with `if(loginButton != null) {`  It's working as expected, but I can't get anything to log or toast in the onSuccess.  It seems as though the onSuccess is not firing.

Comment: try GraphRequest to reterive data as mention in my answer